# I'm using an imported calendar and not sure how to use one of its functions (link to read me file bellow)

Tags: swift, calendar

I am making a calendar in which when a date is pressed it takes you to the corresponding page. The calendar I'm using is Koyomi (https://iosexample.com/simple-customizable-calendar-component-in-swift/ ).
I cant seem to get the function to print the selected date to work.

I've created the calendar and it displays no problem. Also as seen bellow I've added the `func(_: didSelect: forItemAt)` but it seems not to work.

```
public func CalandarView() {
    koyomi.display(in: .current)
    koyomi.isHiddenOtherMonth = false
    koyomi.selectionMode = .single(style: .circle)
    let today = Date()
    koyomi.select(date: today)

    let customColorScheme = (dayBackgrond: UIColor(red: 155/255, green: 150/255, blue: 113/255, alpha: 0.3),
                             weekBackgrond: UIColor(red: 155/255, green: 150/255, blue: 113/255, alpha: 0.8),
                             week: UIColor.black,
                             weekday: UIColor.white,
                             holiday: (saturday: UIColor(red: 183/255, green: 57/255, blue: 21/255, alpha: 1), sunday: UIColor(red: 183/255, green: 57/255, blue: 21/255, alpha: 1)),
                             otherMonth: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8),
                             separator: UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0))

    koyomi.style = KoyomiStyle.custom(customColor: customColorScheme)

    view.addSubview(koyomi)
}

func koyomi(_ Koyomi: Koyomi, didSelect date: Date, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
    let string = formatter.string(from: date)
    print(string)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    CalandarView()
    nextButton()
    previousButton()
    currentButton()
    monthDisplayer()
}
```

The result should simply be a print out of the selected date. Please see the link attached above for more info about the calendar. Any help would be really appreciated since I'm new to coding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys, I've figured it out. I had to add koyomi to class inheritance and change the delegate to self.

Comment: @HuberRzeminski Even I am stuck with same kind issue, Can you check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66204270/how-to-show-2-calenders-and-how-to-disable-future-dates-for-both-too-in-ios and I need your suggestions on this issue